# extract element name values from XSD and import into excel

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, bufferedreader

I have an XSD. I would like to extract the values of "element name=", and write them onto an excel sheet. How do i do this?

The ones in my mind are, bufferedreader/XPATH/jaxb/Apache POI. But I haven't used any of these before. Please help!

Sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gw="XX" xmlns="XXXX" targetNamespace="XXXXX" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:ns0="XXXXXX" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <jaxb:schemaBindings>
                <jaxb:package name="XXXXXXXX" /> 
            </jaxb:schemaBindings>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>

<xsd:import namespace="XXXXXXXX" /> 
<xsd:element name="sample" type="sample" nillable="true" /> 
<xsd:complexType name="sample">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="tempTerms" minOccurs="0" nillable="true">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Input" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" type="ns0:tempTerm" /> 
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="PatternCode" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" gw:type="java.lang.String" /> 
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

sample output:

an XLS where the column names are:

```
sample
tempTerms
Input
PatternCode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath 2.0 expression `distinct-values(//xs:element/@name)` will give you the distinct element names in the schema document. You need to ensure that the XPath processor is set up with the namespace binding xs=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.

In general the result is fairly meaningless. It excludes names of elements in included and imported schema documents, and there may be multiple local element declarations with the same name and different definitions. But it's what you wanted, and if it's not useful, that's your problem not mine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
You were actually right. My **real** task is also to include names of elements in included and imported schema documents. Would the same technique work (XPATH)? Or, would you suggest something else? I was thinking about something along the lines of JAXB/XSOM. I'm not too sure which is the best option though

Comment: Generally, getting information from source XSD documents is tough because there are many ways users can write the same thing. Using an API that gives you access to the compiled schema is much better: for example the Saxon schema processor allows you to dump the compiled schema in an XML format. I would still like to know what the real problem behind the real task is: what are you going to use these element names for?

Comment: Firstly, these XSDs represent data in our database. We later generate several XMLs conforming to each of these XSDs for data transfer tasks. (that's the bigger picture)
Here, we would like to use these excel sheets for storing metadata (provide info like data type, length, description, etc). Its just for our reference. Currently, we manually copy-paste the element names, and also element names in included/imported schema documents. I am trying to automate _at least_ the process of manually copy-pasting the element(and imported/linked)names.
Again, what is the best way to do this? please help